# Working with operator[] and operator=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Given a simple class that overloads the '[ ]' operator:

```
class A
{
  public:
    int operator[](int p_index)
    {
       return a[p_index];
    }

  private:
    int a[5];
};
```

I would like to accomplish the following:

```
void main()
{
   A Aobject;

   Aobject[0] = 1;  // Problem here
}
```

How can I overload the assignment '=' operator in this case to work with the '[ ]' operator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't overload the `=` operator. You return a reference.

```
int& operator[](int p_index)
{
   return a[p_index];
}
```

Make sure to provide a `const` version as well:

```
const int& operator[](int p_index) const
{
   return a[p_index];
}
```

Comment: +1.  In addition, you may want to overload on const: `int operator[](int p_index) const`

Comment: In the const version you can return a plain `int` instead of the `const int &`.

Comment: @David, that's probably not a good idea if you want to take its address. `foo = &a[0];` is broken with `a` being a const `A`.

Answer (score 5):

Make it return a reference:

```
int & operator[](int p_index)
{
   return a[p_index];
}
```

Note that you will also want a const version, which does return a value:

```
int operator[](int p_index) const
{
   return a[p_index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are returning the value which is contained in vaiable a.

In main you are trying to assign int variable which is not available.

You would have seen compilation error "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" like this.

Means the value cannot be assigned to a variable which is not available.

Please change return type of operator []  overloading function into reference or pointer it will work fine.